# Imprimir el numero de cada semana de una fecha en especifico PHP

Tags: php, date

Estoy trabajando con fechas en php pero no logro concretar algo como lo que busco, mi problema es poder visualizar el numero de las semanas que tiene un mes en especifico espero haber sido claro y gracias por su ayuda.
EJEMPLO:

- SEMANAS DE fecha = 2018-03-16 (hoy)

SALIDA:

- WK-9
- WK-10
- WK-11
- WK-12
- WK-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma, utlizando la funcion [strftime](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) de PHP

```
<?php
$date = '2018-03-16';

$firstDay = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date)); // Tomamos el primer día del mes
$lastDay = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($date)); // Y tomamos el ultimo día del mes

$weeks = array();
// Iteramos sobre todos los días del mes, y agregamos al arreglo las semanas solo si no existen previamente
while ($firstDay < $lastDay) {
    $week = strftime('%V', strtotime($firstDay));
    if (!in_array($week, $weeks)) {
        $weeks[] = strftime('%V', strtotime($firstDay));
    }
    $firstDay = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime($firstDay . ' +1 day'));
}
?>
```

En el caso de hoy imprime:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '09' (length=2)
  1 => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => string '11' (length=2)
  3 => string '12' (length=2)
  4 => string '13' (length=2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder efectivamente es acorde a mi duda y resuelve mi problema un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Tu mejor aliado para esto sería usar un objeto `DateTime`.

Ahora bien, en algunos casos la semana comienza el domingo, en otros la semana comienza el lunes.

Veamos un ejemplo para cada caso:

### Semana empezando el domingo

```
$fecha = new DateTime('first Sunday of this month');
$esteMes = $fecha->format('m');

while ($fecha->format('m') === $esteMes) {
    echo $fecha->format('W').PHP_EOL;
    $fecha->modify('next Sunday');
}
```

**Salida:**

```
09
10
11
12
```

---

#### Semana empezando el lunes

```
$fecha = new DateTime('first Monday of this month');
$esteMes = $fecha->format('m');

while ($fecha->format('m') === $esteMes) {
    echo $fecha->format('W').PHP_EOL;
    $fecha->modify('next Monday');
}
```

**Salida:**

```
10
11
12
13
```

Comment: Gracias por responder es muy clara tu respuesta, pero que pasa cuando en el caso especifico de este mes, marzo de 2018 la primer semana no comienza en lunes ni tampoco en domingo, es decir el primer dia de marzo commienza en jueves, de esta manera estaria dejando fuera la semana (WK-09) del mes de marzo, ¿me explico?

Comment: @JrojasE en ese caso tendrías que poner **`$fecha = new DateTime('first Thursday of this month');`** y dentro del `while` poner: **`$fecha->modify('next Thursday');`**. A mí me imprime: `09,10,11,12,13`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
echo date_format($fecha,"W");
```

Lo anterior imprime el número de la semana de la fecha informada en la variable **$fecha**

Comment: si habia provado esa opcion amigo, "$semana= date('W');
echo "WK".$semana;" pero el problema es que ocupo todas las semanas del mes en cuestion y en este caso solo imprime la semana actual del mes

Comment: @JrojasE no vas a encontrar algo que te haga la tarea directamente, debes tomar una fecha e ir sumándole días (+7) y así ir avanzando en el calendario a la vez que obtienes los números de las semanas.